# Sizeof() varies with the same input

Tags: c

```
void main()
{
printf("%d\n",sizeof('1'));
}
```

Output : 4

```
void main()
{
char a='1';
printf("%d\n",sizeof(a));
}
```

Output : 1

Can somebody say why it is different ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In C, character literals are of type `int`.

Note that this was changed in C++, in which character literals have the obvious type `char`.

Answer (score 1):

In C, character literals are of type `int`, in another word, `sizeof('1')` is the same as `sizeof(int)`.

While `sizeof(a)` is the real `sizeof(char)`.